# how to find hidden video src using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, hidden-field

In general, It is possible to download the video by right-click.
But I don't know how to find this video's src using selenium.

```
<div id="video-processing" class="video-processing hidden">Processing video, please check back in a while</div>
<video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin hidden" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://i3.ruliweb.com/profile/16/12/01/158b9f7cb02326425.jpeg"></video>
```

I needs your help. thanks.

Comment: when you say src do you mean the content of the poster attribute?

Comment: I think you have to go using mouse event like right click >  click download option

Comment: Cathal // no, that is only video's thumnail image src. I want to know video's src.

Comment: @User8392, are you that there is no child element called `<source>` ?

Comment: @Andersson // there is not <source>...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like your question,
If you can not find the `src` by Inspect by browser Or get the page **source code** by Python (For various reasons, such as controlling several quality of video or for security & police reasons) ➡
One hundred percent is being changed by JavaScript. Otherwise should have been visible in the **HTML** code.
So I have a very simple recommendation and that is to use this code in Console:

```
var x = document.getElementsById("video-player").getAttribute("src");
console.log(x);
alert(x);
```

Of course, it would be much better if you give the site Address.